# Unity Quality Reduction only reduces my player sprite quality

Tags: 2d, tiled, unity

I created a small map in tiled then imported it into Unity. A small sprite character is controlled by the player to roam about the map. I am experimenting with this for University and wanted to see the effect reducing the graphics quality had on the game and machine. So I created an executable and before playing I chose a lower quality setting. However, choosing a lower setting results in only the character becoming more pixelated, the map graphics is completely unaffected.

I assume this is to do with Tiled?

How could I reduce the quality of the map in Unity? Or does it have to be done in tiled?

**EDIT

The map was imported via Tiled2Unity.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the specifics of how it was imported into Unity? In particular which library you used, since Unity does not have native support for Tiled. From the looks of the map, I'm pretty sure I know what tutorial you were following...

Comment: @jhocking Hey, it was imported via Tiled2Unity

Comment: Could it be that the quality setting in Unity affects the maximum texture size, and that your player sprite is part of a larger texture than the texture that contains the tiles?